# Moving image to specific folder not working

Tags: php

I am unable to move my image to the folder C:\wamp64\www\mywork\images

I am trying to create a simple program where I can upload my pictures to the folder but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $target = "./images/".$image;
        echo $image; echo $target;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["name"],$target);
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <form method="POST" action="manage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
            <input type="file" name="image">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" name="upload">POST</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`move_uploaded_file()` needs the **temporary** filename / path

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your target destination folder to this

```
$target = "images/".$image;
```

You can also use the server document root as

```
$target = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/mywork/images/".$image;
```

If the above does not work, get the specific errors using the following :

```
print_r($_FILES['image']['error']);
```